# Where do i get android package in expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Cannot find a package similar to "com.test.app" in app.json expo project

```
"android": {
  "config": {
    "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-5011065144052286~3305273933"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it yourself in app.json like this:

```
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.test.app"
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.test.app",
}
```

The package and bundleIdentifier can be anything but it needs to be unique on the App Store and Google Play Store